# Speed up a while loop that conditionally creates a new variable in R

Tags: performance, r

I would like to speed up the following code in R. This is a loop to define new individuals (column `newID`) when the variable `change` is equal to 1. Any idea on how to improve the loop will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
## Build the data frame 
dat <- expand.grid(x = 1:1000, ID = as.character(seq(0, 4000, 1)))
dat$change <- 0
dat[which(dat$x == 1), c("change")] <- 1
dat[which(dat$x == 300), c("change")] <- 1
dat[which(dat$x == 700), c("change")] <- 1
dat[1, c("change")] <- 0

## Add a column "newID"
dat$newID <- NA
index <- c(1, which(dat$change == 1), nrow(dat))
j <- 1
i <- 1

system.time(while (j < length(index)){
  print(paste(j, "/", length(index), sep = " "))
  i <- ifelse((j > 1) && (dat[index[j], c("ID")] != dat[index[j - 1], c("ID")]), 1, i)
  ## print(i)
  if(j == length(index) - 1){
    dat[seq(index[j], index[j + 1], by = 1), c("newID")] <- paste("Ind ", dat[index[j], c("ID")], "|", i, sep="")
  } else{
    dat[seq(index[j], index[j + 1] - 1, by = 1), c("newID")] <- paste("Ind ", dat[index[j], c("ID")], "|", i, sep="")
  }
  j <- j + 1
  i <- i + 1
})
## summary(dat)
```

Here is an example:

The input data frame has 3 columns. In particular, `ID` is the ID number of each individual and `change` takes the value of 1 when the individual is renewed.

```
    x ID   change
1   1  0      0
2   2  0      0
3   3  0      0
4   4  0      0
5   5  0      1
6   6  0      0
7   7  0      1
8   8  0      0
9   9  0      0
10 10  0      0
11  1  1      1
12  2  1      0
13  3  1      0
14  4  1      0
15  5  1      1
16  6  1      0
17  7  1      1
18  8  1      0
19  9  1      0
20 10  1      0
21  1  2      1
22  2  2      0
23  3  2      0
24  4  2      0
25  5  2      1
26  6  2      0
27  7  2      1
28  8  2      0
29  9  2      0
30 10  2      0
```

The variable `newID` is created as follows:
When `change` is equal to 1, `newID` takes the old ID number and the increment value. Thus, in the example, the expected result is:

```
    x  ID  change newID
1   1  0      0 Ind 0|1
2   2  0      0 Ind 0|1
3   3  0      0 Ind 0|1
4   4  0      0 Ind 0|1
5   5  0      1 Ind 0|2
6   6  0      0 Ind 0|2
7   7  0      1 Ind 0|3
8   8  0      0 Ind 0|3
9   9  0      0 Ind 0|3
10 10  0      0 Ind 0|3
11  1  1      1 Ind 1|1
12  2  1      0 Ind 1|1
13  3  1      0 Ind 1|1
14  4  1      0 Ind 1|1
15  5  1      1 Ind 1|2
16  6  1      0 Ind 1|2
17  7  1      1 Ind 1|3
18  8  1      0 Ind 1|3
19  9  1      0 Ind 1|3
20 10  1      0 Ind 1|3
21  1  2      1 Ind 2|1
22  2  2      0 Ind 2|1
23  3  2      0 Ind 2|1
24  4  2      0 Ind 2|1
25  5  2      1 Ind 2|2
26  6  2      0 Ind 2|2
27  7  2      1 Ind 2|3
28  8  2      0 Ind 2|3
29  9  2      0 Ind 2|3
30 10  2      0 Ind 2|3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Do not use explicit loops unless you absolutely have to

Many functions in R are vectorized and your code will be much faster if you leverage this instead of writing your own loops.

For example, you can compute the first part of your `newID` with a single `paste()` call:

```
dat$newID <- paste("Ind", dat$ID)
```

```
    x ID change newID
1   1  0      0 Ind 0
2   2  0      0 Ind 0
3   3  0      0 Ind 0
4   4  0      0 Ind 0
5   5  0      1 Ind 0
6   6  0      0 Ind 0
7   7  0      1 Ind 0
8   8  0      0 Ind 0
9   9  0      0 Ind 0
10 10  0      0 Ind 0
11  1  1      1 Ind 1
12  2  1      0 Ind 1
13  3  1      0 Ind 1
14  4  1      0 Ind 1
15  5  1      1 Ind 1
16  6  1      0 Ind 1
17  7  1      1 Ind 1
18  8  1      0 Ind 1
19  9  1      0 Ind 1
...
```

### The second part of your `newID` is simply the cumulative sum of `change`

The most tricky part here is to reset the counter each time the `ID` changes. A way to do this is to use the function `by`, which will execute a given function on a group of rows depending on the values of a grouping variable (here `ID`):

```
by(dat, dat$ID, function(x) {
  cumsum(x$change)
})
```

```
dat$ID: 0
 [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dat$ID: 1
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dat$ID: 2
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

The two issues here are:

- `by` returns a list so we have to use `unlist()` before trying to put the result in a data.frame column

```
dat$newID <- unlist(by(dat, dat$ID, function(x) {
  cumsum(x$change)
}))
```

- because `change` doesn't start with 1, the values for the first `ID` are shifted by one. We can fix this by changing the first value manually.

### Put everything together

```
dat$change[1] <- 1

dat$newID <- unlist(by(dat, dat$ID, function(x) {
  cumsum(x$change)
}))

dat$newID <- paste0("Ind ", dat$ID, "|", dat$newID)
```

And you get exactly the output you were asking for, without any explicit `for` loops!